# A question about the disruption of global geochemical cycle in anthropocene

Tags: biogeochemistry

We often only hear of problems with the carbon, nitrogen & water cycles etc.

I would like to know if there have been any observed problems with other cycles - for example, the iron cycle, magnesium cycle or potassium cycle, if these particular cycles exist, which could be attributed to have caused some major sustainability issues (e.g. loss of arable land)? I do not have much knowledge in this area.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Are you asking if other geochemical cycles exist?

Comment: He/she wants to know about human disturbances in cycles of other minerals. But this is way too broad.

Comment: Related: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chemgeo.2016.11.029

Comment: Phosphorus would be an example. We (mankind) uses large amounts of phosphate as fertilizer. It is washed away through rivers into the oceans (t.e. leading to algae blooms there). We do not recapture it and in some (some more) years there might be a shortage of phosphate.